# improvements in is_array statement before foreach with ternary operator php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, ternary-operator

I have

```
if ( is_array($this->input->post("tolerance")) )
   foreach($this->input->post("tolerance")  as $tolerance) 
           $tolerances      .= $tolerance . " " ;
else
    $tolerances = 'Not defined';
```

I want to short code as we all know we are verifying if it is a an array before getting array values

so what would be the correct way to shorten this?

```
is_array($this->input->post("tolerance")) ? foreach($this->input->post("tolerance") as tolerance)  $tolerances .= $tolerance . " " : $tolerances = 'Not defined';
```

Comment: Use shorter variable names. Seriously: Don't shorten it, you will never be able to read and understand your code again

Comment: Be careful: its better to have readable code than 'shortened' code - there is very little to be gained here I feel... - I would ad some braces for code blocks too - just to make it super clear...

Comment: **Why** do you want to shorten the code? Doesn't it work as is? Also, I find the missing braces a bad practice, the code is more readable if you use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any good way doing this, but be mean and do a:

```
/* @ == ignore expected warning, $r == assign on testing */
$tolerances = ($r = @implode(' ', $this->input->post("tolerance")) ) ? $r : 'Not defined';
```

I know, most people see this as bad practice.

Another option, to use foreach:

```
$tolerances = is_array($arr=$this->input->post("tolerance")) ? call_user_func(function($p) { foreach($p as $t) $ts .= $t . " "; return $ts;}, $arr) : 'Not defined';
```

just following the 'bad practice' philosophy: if its possible, its meant to be.

Answer (score 4):

You should/can NOT shorten this at all while keeping the `foreach`. The ternary operator is not meant to be used like this. It for expressions, not for statements.

Good example:

```
$foo = xyz() ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

Bad example:

```
xyz() ? foo() : bar();
```

Worse example (syntax error):

```
is_array($foo) ? foreach($foo as $bar) ...
```

---

The only proper way to shorten your code is using a temporary variable and `implode` instead of the loop:

```
$tolerance = $this->input->post('tolerance');
$tolerance = is_array($tolerance) ? implode(' ', $tolerance) : 'Not defined';
```

In this case the ternary operator is perfectly fine since now you just have a expressions in the then/else parts instead of statements.

Comment: Is there a way to shorten this?

Comment: well you can keep the foreach kind of.. see my post (wrapping it into a call_user_func() call)

Answer (score 2):

Try with `implode()`, like this:

```
$tolerances = is_array($this->input->post("tolerance")) ? implode(' ', $this->input->post("tolerance")) : 'Not defined' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tolerances = ( is_array($this->input->post("tolerance")) == false ) ? "Not defined" : implode(" ", implode($this->input->post("tolerance"))) ;
```

Comment: `== false` and `== true` are truly horrible when you are dealing with booleans anyway